# Wordpress pages & posts won't update

Tags: wordpress, caching

For two days now, my home page and a few posts won't update on my Wordpress. I can save modifications, but they won't appear on the front end. Weirdly, the admin bar doesn't appear anymore on these pages and posts.

I've tried to purge, deactivate and change my cache plug-in, disabled all my plugins one by one, but I can't figure out what causes this issue, and why on just a few pages.

Here are the [home page](https://www.revue-ballast.fr), a [post where it happens](https://www.revue-ballast.fr/penser-limmigration-olivier-besancenot-et-daniele-obono/) and a [post where there is no issue](https://www.revue-ballast.fr/patrice-martin-foret/).

I now use W3 Total Cache but the issue appeared with WP Super Cache & Autoptimize.

Comment: Have you opened the developer console on any of these pages? My guess is that your getting a sleet storm of errors in the Network and Console.

Comment: Start by disabling all cache plugins (especially Autoptimize). You should then delete all files in your **/wp-content/cache/** directory. Look for any reference to cache in your wp-config.php and .htaccess files and comment out temporarily.

Comment: Thanks. I've uninstalled Autoptimize. I disabled W3 Total Cache, deleted the files in cache/ and there's no reference of cache in wp-config.php and .htaccess. Here is the console on the homepage (while logged) : https://justpaste.it/6g1zr and I don't see any error on the network console.

Comment: But I can see that on the pages with the issue, this Autoptimize minified file is still loaded, even though I've deleted the plugin-in and the file via FTP https://www.revue-ballast.fr/wp-content/cache/autoptimize/css/autoptimize_cd91d8b0b92a77e6d5741a0c57336b7c.css

Comment: I see that too. There is a support answer [here] (https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-delete-autoptimize/)

Comment: I just did a Ctrl+F5 (hard reload) on your home page and it seems to have worked ... Clear your browser cache and reload your home page

Comment: OK so now the home page has been updated but still no admin bar. Well actually it appears erratically.

Comment: You have to [login again](https://www.revue-ballast.fr/wp-admin) after you clear your browser cache

Comment: I would recommend never installing Autoptimize again and using [Google PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/)

Comment: Even after login again, the admin bar doesn't appear on the home page and some posts... Thanks for the advice about Autoptimize.